# How to print nested loops quicker in c?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, optimization, nested

I am trying to create a maze like game in c with double arrays and macros.
But it is taking the console way too long to printf the whole maze.
Is there a faster method for this.

```
#define SIZER 25 //row
#define SIZEC 50 //column

#define WALL "\xDB"
#define MAN "O"
#define ENEMY "\x40"
#define EMPTY " "

void print_game()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<SIZER;++i){
        for(j=0;j<SIZEC;++j){
            if(game[i][j]==w)
                printf(WALL);
            else if(game[i][j]==m)
                printf(MAN);
            else if(game[i][j]==x)
                printf(ENEMY);
            else if(game[i][j]==e)
                printf(EMPTY);
            if(j==SIZEC-1)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `ncurses`?

Comment: I would rather not to. But if they are that effective i might try.

Comment: Instead of making many calls to `printf`, each printing a single character, buffer the whole screen and print it all at once with a single call.

Comment: @RobertStiffler Can you describe it a bit more. Or give me a research topic about it. Because i am very new to c programming and don't know much about buffer manipulations.

Comment: With the current implementation, you are calling `printf` 20x50=1000 times to print the board. It would be much more efficient to build one string for the whole game board and call `printf` only once. The buffer could be as simple as `char buffer[1300]`. You'll need 1300 chars (26x50) because you'll need to add newlines at the end of each line.

Comment: @RobertStiffler Thank you all. Also with helps of bodo and abelenky i created an mixed solution of putchar and buffered output. Case closed :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version creates a complete line before calling `printf`. This could be extended to combine the whole maze into a string as mentioned in Robert Stiffler's comment.

```
#define SIZER 25 //row
#define SIZEC 50 //column

#define WALL '\xDB'
#define MAN 'O'
#define ENEMY '\x40'
#define EMPTY ' '

void print_game()
{
    int i,j;
    char line[SIZEC + 1];
    for(i=0;i<SIZER;++i){
        for(j=0;j<SIZEC;++j){
            if(game[i][j]==w)
                line[j] = WALL;
            else if(game[i][j]==m)
                line[j] = MAN;
            else if(game[i][j]==x)
                line[j] = ENEMY;
            else if(game[i][j]==e)
                line[j] = EMPTY;
        }
        line[SIZEC] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is an incredibly slow function, because it needs to be able to parse complex strings with multiple `%` formatters and width-specifiers in them.

If you don't really need the rich functionality of `printf` switching to `puts` (*put-string*) or `putchar` (*put-character*) should be much faster.

---

I also like @RobertStifiller's comment suggesting that you append all the output into an in-memory array, then call an output function just once at the very end to print all data at once.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That really helped me to understand buffers.